# CSRF Django, ValueError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-csrf

I follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) but i get the following error

ValueError at /mapapp/
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

These are all the files which has csrf related code in them

**views.py**

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from mapvis.store import *
import datetime

def mapapp(request):
    csrfprotection = {}
    csrfprotection.update(csrf(request))

....

    return render_to_response('mapvis/mapapp.html', c, csrfprotection)
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

**mappapp.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <strong>Start</strong><br>
  Lng: <input type="text" id="start_lng"><br>
  Lat: <input type="text" id="start_lat"><br>
  <strong>Destination</strong><br>
  Lng: <input type="text" id="dest_lng"><br>
  Lat: <input type="text" id="dest_lat"><br>
  <input type="submit" style="background-color:#64FE2E" type="button" id="go" value="go"> 
</form> 
</body>
```

:EDIT

```
Internal Server Error: /mapapp/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sw/django-1.5.4/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/piehe154/maps/lmap/mapvis/views.py", line 28, in mapapp
    return render_to_response('mapvis/mapapp.html', c, csrfprotection)
  File "/sw/django-1.5.4/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 29, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
  File "/sw/django-1.5.4/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 175, in render_to_string
    context_instance.update(dictionary)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full stacktrace and error?

Comment: Does `mapvis.store` define something called `csrf`, by any chance?

Comment: Daniel, no it does not.

Comment: As @Shes mentioned; the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) said, your second parameter must be *dict of values* that will be passed to the template and your third argument must be context_instance. You are passing wrong arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the following lines, they aren't needed:

```
csrfprotection = {}
csrfprotection.update(csrf(request))
```

But make sure you use RequestContext when rendering to a template:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def mapapp(request):
    # context contains key/value pairs used in your template
    c = "GOOGLE_API_KEY"
    context = { 'myvariable': 'thevalue', 'c': c }
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('mapvis/mapapp.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If you don't want to use RequestContext though, your view code should look like:

```
def mapapp(request):
    # context contains key/value pairs used in your template
    c = "GOOGLE_API_KEY"
    context = { 'myvariable': 'thevalue', 'c': c }
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('mapvis/mapapp.html', context)
```

Comment: This only works if you use `RequestContext` in the `render_to_response` call (or the `render` shortcut), which OP isn't.

Comment: return render_to_response('mapvis/mapapp.html', c, {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) gives me "global name 'RequestContext' is not defined"

Comment: Not sure what i should have in 'my_variable': 'thevalue'}, using your example without RequestContext i get the same error message from the inital post.

Comment: You're not copying my example though, because you have a random variable `c` that you're trying to pass to render_to_response. Get rid of it, or put it INSIDE `context`.